# to use or not to use CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, oracle, syntax

What is the difference between the following syntax:

```
CONSTRAINT user_roles_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(role_id),
CONSTRAINT students_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
CONSTRAINT ratings_institute_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(institute_id) REFERENCES institutes(institute_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT ratings_ip_uq UNIQUE(ip)
```

and

```
PRIMARY KEY (role_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
UNIQUE(ip)
FOREIGN KEY (institute_id) REFERENCES institutes(institutes_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

i used the first set of code while writing create statements in the oracle sql developer. unfortunately i am having to convert the oracle code into mysql to run on xampp.

Comment: The first set gives the constraints a specific name the second one doesn't and leaves it up to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can either specify then names using the `CONSTRAINT contraint_name ...` syntax or you can leave it out and Oracle will name the constraint as something like `SYS_C123456`. Naming the constraint yourself makes it a lot easier to debug the code as getting errors like:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST.SYS_C009329) violated - parent key not found
```

does not tell you much about what column you got something wrong for - but:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST.ROLES__INSTITUTE_ID__FK) violated - parent key not found
```

tells you exactly the table and column where the error occurred (if you name your constraints with enough detail).

You can see the difference in the constraint names here:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE students ( id INT CONSTRAINT students__id__pk PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE institutes( id INT CONSTRAINT institutes__id__pk PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE roles(
  role_id      INT,
  student_id   INT,
  institute_id INT,
  ip           VARCHAR2(15),
  CONSTRAINT roles__role_id__pk PRIMARY KEY(role_id),
  CONSTRAINT roles__student_id__fk
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(id),
  CONSTRAINT roles__institute_id__fk
    FOREIGN KEY(institute_id) REFERENCES institutes(id),
  CONSTRAINT roles__ip__u UNIQUE(ip) 
);


CREATE TABLE roles1(
  role_id      INT,
  student_id   INT,
  institute_id INT,
  ip           VARCHAR2(15),
  PRIMARY KEY(role_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(institute_id) REFERENCES institutes(id),
  UNIQUE(ip) 
);
```

**Query - Named Constraints**

```
SELECT constraint_name,
       constraint_type,
       index_name,
       r_constraint_name
FROM   USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  table_name = 'ROLES';
```

**Output**:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE INDEX_NAME                     R_CONSTRAINT_NAME            
------------------------------ --------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ROLES__ROLE_ID__PK             P               ROLES__ROLE_ID__PK                                            
ROLES__IP__U                   U               ROLES__IP__U                                                  
ROLES__STUDENT_ID__FK          R                                              STUDENTS__ID__PK               
ROLES__INSTITUTE_ID__FK        R                                              INSTITUTES__ID__PK
```

**Query 2 - Unnamed Constraints**:

```
SELECT constraint_name,
       constraint_type,
       index_name,
       r_constraint_name
FROM   USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  table_name = 'ROLES1';
```

**Output**:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE INDEX_NAME                     R_CONSTRAINT_NAME            
------------------------------ --------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS_C009326                    P               SYS_C009326                                                   
SYS_C009327                    U               SYS_C009327                                                   
SYS_C009328                    R                                              STUDENTS__ID__PK               
SYS_C009329                    R                                              INSTITUTES__ID__PK
```

[MySQL is similar but gives the constraints slightly better default names - but not by much.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fe64/2)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the 2nd index, where the foreign keys reference different fields, the 4 constraints are the same. However, even in mysql you can follow the constraint like syntax, see mysql documentation on [create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
 create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
      [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | {FULLTEXT|SPATIAL} [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
      [index_name] (index_col_name,...) reference_definition
  | CHECK (expr)
```

Furthermore, you can use oracle with apache and php, so you do not have to replace oracle just because a pre-packaged installer does not have oracle configured by default.

Answer (score 0):

The **`CONSTRAINT`** keyword is optional in MySQL and (if memory serves) in Oracle. Its purpose is to allow you to explicitly name the constraint, which helps to provide self-documentation and also is useful if you later need to disable the constraint or drop or rebuild an associated index.